# How can I increase the return from from ads?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, revenue, advertisements

I made a little Windows Phone game and I want to use AdRotator to show ads in the game. My game has 50 levels. Some levels take 30 seconds, other levels more than 3 minutes to complete them.

Will I make more money with longer levels? Can I get more impressions in longer levels?

My game has a free trial mode, but you have to buy the game if you want the entire content.

How can I increase impressions and get a high eCPM rate?

Comment: Make a better game? No offense, but did you ever consider that perhaps your game is just not good/interesting/engaging?

Comment: It's not about the quality of the game. I just want to know how to get more impressions and a high eCPM with the same amount of users. For example, a user plays my game during 2 minutes. Another user plays it 5 minutes. Will I get more impressions from the second user because he plays my game during a longer time interval?

Comment: There is no formula for where and when to display commercials. Too much and the user wont keep playing your game, to little and you wont make any money. And to force the user to buy the entire game AND have commercials would make me want to slap the creator in the face. Either have free full with commercials or payed version without.

Comment: I want to show the commercials just in the free version. The payed version is without ads.